# Filtering Data Frame by Multiple Criteria Based on Separate Index Vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

I have a data frame with multiple column fields of data one of which is an index variable.  It's essentially multiple time-series of transactions related to a particular unique identifier (the separate index vector).  I'd like to filter this data frame provided the following criteria are met:

Time elapsed (in days) between the first entry for the corresponding index (top being most recent date) being less than 90 days and the transaction type being either a P-Purchase if the first entry is an S-Sale or vice versa (if Sale and then Purchase).

I'm not sure if I should use an If else statement or dplyr's case.when method so I'm struggling with how to solve this.

Here is a sample of the scripts of my work (which is generating an error) using either if else or dplyr:

**With for loop and dplyr**

```
for (i in length(ciknumbers2)) {
    data10 <- if(InsiderList3$`Insider CIK` == ciknumbers2[i])
    filter(head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`,1)-InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`< 90 &
    head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`,1) != InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`) 
}
```

**- Just dplyr**

```
filt_data <- InsiderList3 %>%    
  filter(
    if (`Insider CIK` == ciknumbers2) {
      head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`,1)-InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`<90 & head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`,1) != InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`
    } else {

    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(totalrows = nrow(.)) %>%
  summarize()

InsiderList3 %>% 
  filter(case_when(`Insider CIK` == ciknumbers2, 
                   head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`,1)-InsiderList3$`Transaction Date`< 90,
                  head(InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`,1) != InsiderList3$`Transaction Type`
         )) %>% 
  tail(1)
```

The index list is:

```
"0001337645" "0001749420" "0001658704" "0001642765" "000852412"  "0001499263" "0001769077" "0001239635" "0001790576" "0001198046"
```

And the data frame looks like this:

[image]

Help constructing a solution under either method would be much appreciated.

## Update with Sample dput

```
dput(InsiderList5)
structure(list(`Insider CIK` = c("0001337645", "0001337645", 
"0001337645", "0001337645", "0001337645", "0001337645", "0001337645", 
"0001337645", "0001337645"), `Insider Full Name and CIK` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bachmann Lisa M (0001337645)", 
"Robins Ronald A Jr (0001499263)", "Strub Robert (0001769077)", 
"Mueller Andrej (0001790576)", "Schlonsky Michael Allen (0001557088)", 
"SRS Investment Management, LLC (0001503174)", "JAMES MICHAEL C (0001365831)", 
"THORN BRUCE K (0001215178)", "Ramsden Jonathan E (0001451778)", 
"PATEL GOYAL KRUTI (0001770886)", "Asmar Christian (0001787532)", 
"Bergman Artur (0001769490)", "Castillo Kirsten (0001808806)", 
"Andres Juan (0001760670)", "Jolson Joseph A (0001398113)", "Wilson Jan C. (0001807821)", 
"Beeler Brian K (0001641580)", "Magnuson Lee A (0001726150)", 
"Fernandes Prabhavathi (0001540883)", "Osbourn William F Jr (0001421529)", 
"Morno-Wade Suzan (0001761233)", "Mancini Joseph H. (0001573159)", 
"Pasquale Maria E (0001736295)", "STERN ADAM K (0001403497)", 
"Heiss Xavier (0001803559)", "Feldman Michael David (0001693649)", 
"Dellovo Victor (0001484174)", "Dhanak Dashyant (0001760682)", 
"Robinson Douglas (0001383267)", "Barry Corie S (0001676999)", 
"KLAERNER GERRIT (0001743681)", "GAY JOHN M. (0001765684)", "Tiscornia Anthony D (0001707972)", 
"Nefkens Michael G (0001566846)", "Shulkin David (0001808395)", 
"STAFFORD JOHN S III (0001218981)", "Nelson Connia M (0001767555)", 
"Boyd Steven (0001706140)", "ARMISTICE CAPITAL, LLC (0001601086)", 
"LAROCHE RICHARD F JR (0001012859)", "Holloman James Phillip (0001424987)"
), class = "factor"), `Acquistion or Disposition` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "D", "-"), class = "factor"), 
    `Transaction Date` = structure(c(18358, 18353, 18353, 18333, 
    18332, 18332, 18330, 18290, 18155), class = "Date"), `Deemed Execution Date` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Â", "2020-01-02"
    ), class = "factor"), Issuer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BIG LOTS INC", "GMS Inc.", 
    "ABERCROMBIE & FITCH CO /DE/", "GREEN DOT CORP", "AVIS BUDGET GROUP, INC.", 
    "GUIDED THERAPEUTICS INC", "Terra Tech Corp.", "MENS WEARHOUSE INC", 
    "PETSMART INC", "TAILORED BRANDS INC", "ETSY INC", "AVID TECHNOLOGY, INC.", 
    "Fastly, Inc.", "Ocugen, Inc.", "Avantor, Inc.", "Evelo Biosciences, Inc.", 
    "Moderna, Inc.", "Harvest Capital Credit Corp", "JMP GROUP LLC", 
    "Spartan Energy Acquisition Corp.", "Horizon Pharma plc", 
    "Horizon Therapeutics Public Ltd Co", "RAVEN INDUSTRIES INC", 
    "Cempra Holdings, LLC", "CEMPRA, INC.", "TIME WARNER CABLE INC.", 
    "XEROX CORP", "Xerox Holdings Corp", "INCYTE CORP", "DarioHealth Corp.", 
    "INVIVO THERAPEUTICS HOLDINGS CORP.", "LabStyle Innovations Corp.", 
    "Matinas BioPharma Holdings, Inc.", "Modigene Inc.", "ORGANOVO HOLDINGS, INC.", 
    "PROLOR Biotech, Inc.", "CSP INC /MA/", "VERINT SYSTEMS INC", 
    "BEST BUY CO INC", "DOMINOS PIZZA INC", "Tricida, Inc.", 
    "Novan, Inc.", "Coupa Software Inc", "DXC Technology Co", 
    "Hewlett Packard Enterprise Co", "RESIDEO TECHNOLOGIES, INC.", 
    "ORASURE TECHNOLOGIES INC", "AWARE INC /MA/", "Xencor Inc", 
    "Hudson Global, Inc.", "Cerecor Inc.", "AMAG PHARMACEUTICALS, INC.", 
    "AYTU BIOSCIENCE, INC", "EYEGATE PHARMACEUTICALS INC", "INNOVUS PHARMACEUTICALS, INC.", 
    "ReShape Lifesciences Inc.", "CROSS BORDER RESOURCES, INC.", 
    "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", "CINTAS CORP", "ROCKWELL AUTOMATION INC", 
    "ROCKWELL AUTOMATION, INC"), class = "factor"), Form = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "3", "5", 
    "4/A", "3/A"), class = "factor"), `Transaction Type` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A-Award", "F-InKind", 
    "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "-", "G-Gift", "W-Will", "J-Other", 
    "P-Purchase", "X-InTheMoney", "D-Return", "C-Conversion", 
    "I-Discretionary"), class = "factor"), `Direct or Indirect Ownership` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("--D", "-ED", 
    "--I", "1-I", "---", "-EI"), class = "factor"), `Number of Securities Transacted` = structure(c(44L, 
    49L, 34L, 54L, 16L, 30L, 17L, 53L, 51L), .Label = c("10133.0000", 
    "10500.0000", "11165.0000", "11651.0000", "12559.0000", "12962.0000", 
    "14200.0000", "15452.0000", "16563.0000", "17386.0000", "17500.0000", 
    "17574.0000", "18349.0000", "18835.0000", "18917.0000", "19453.0000", 
    "1976.0000", "1988.0000", "20396.0000", "20614.0000", "2156.0000", 
    "2169.0000", "2231.0000", "22343.0000", "24000.0000", "24150.0000", 
    "24750.0000", "2750.0000", "2751.0000", "2912.0000", "29733.0000", 
    "2986.0000", "30643.0000", "3166.0000", "3228.0000", "3326.0000", 
    "3502.0000", "3610.0000", "36650.0000", "37831.0000", "4136.0000", 
    "4499.0000", "4536.0000", "46634.0000", "50000.0000", "5800.0000", 
    "6048.0000", "6479.0000", "6980.0000", "7517.0000", "8579.0000", 
    "9241.0000", "941.0000", "9488.0000", "9538.0000", "", "1000.0000", 
    "10000.0000", "1009.0000", "11714.0000", "1200.0000", "1398.0000", 
    "1405.0000", "1483.0000", "17482.0000", "194.0000", "198.0000", 
    "2000.0000", "2213.0000", "250.0000", "2885.0000", "2957.0000", 
    "29636.0000", "3662.0000", "395.0000", "400.0000", "4400.0000", 
    "4709.0000", "5000.0000", "5200.0000", "5474.0000", "566.0000", 
    "600.0000", "6000.0000", "603.0000", "650.0000", "6801.0000", 
    "6841.0000", "7000.0000", "784.0000", "9503.0000", "9740.0000", 
    "1457.0000", "20000.0000", "33208.0000", "40000.0000", "4603.0000", 
    "526.0000", "6348.0000", "8037.0000", "16753.0000", "26672.0000", 
    "100.0000", "1048.0000", "1073.0000", "1080.0000", "10962.0000", 
    "11349.0000", "1212.0000", "1249.0000", "12698.0000", "1314.0000", 
    "1354.0000", "1358.0000", "14900.0000", "15000.0000", "15765.0000", 
    "1607.0000", "1668.0000", "17103.0000", "1748.0000", "20003.0000", 
    "2067.0000", "2092.0000", "2158.0000", "2398.0000", "2496.0000", 
    "2602.0000", "3002.0000", "30442.0000", "3057.0000", "3183.0000", 
    "3750.0000", "4102.0000", "4200.0000", "4500.0000", "4556.0000", 
    "4785.0000", "4972.0000", "5238.0000", "6161.0000", "6600.0000", 
    "675.0000", "679.0000", "686.0000", "8201.0000", "8461.0000", 
    "9518.0000", "1.0000", "1070300.0000", "1122700.0000", "1376795.0000", 
    "1588800.0000", "1621445.0000", "213321.0000", "288439.0000", 
    "3500.0000", "3500000.0000", "400000.0000", "4189300.0000", 
    "500000.0000", "1100.0000", "11500.0000", "120000.0000", 
    "1200000.0000", "12500.0000", "125000.0000", "134.0000", 
    "1500.0000", "150000.0000", "1500000.0000", "151162.0000", 
    "160000.0000", "185724.0000", "190000.0000", "1935.0000", 
    "200000.0000", "2000000.0000", "215196.0000", "240.0000", 
    "244133.0000", "2500.0000", "250000.0000", "27320.0000", 
    "2900.0000", "3100.0000", "3300.0000", "35000.0000", "3900.0000", 
    "4000.0000", "450000.0000", "4600.0000", "490196.0000", "500.0000", 
    "51282.0000", "5300.0000", "5400.0000", "54429.0000", "54430.0000", 
    "5500.0000", "58168.0000", "600000.0000", "6100.0000", "64599.0000", 
    "6500.0000", "67680.0000", "7100.0000", "7560.0000", "7565.0000", 
    "76865.0000", "800000.0000", "900000.0000", "91465.0000", 
    "9700.0000", "10010.0000", "105135.0000", "1069.0000", "115911.0000", 
    "12.0000", "12213.0000", "1452.0000", "16812.0000", "17895.0000", 
    "1860.0000", "19050.0000", "1961.0000", "19653.0000", "21046.0000", 
    "2138.0000", "21600.0000", "21815.0000", "219.0000", "23235.0000", 
    "2351.0000", "2721.0000", "2777.0000", "2981.0000", "31026.0000", 
    "35211.0000", "3565.0000", "40585.0000", "4509.0000", "48351.0000", 
    "4938.0000", "49926.0000", "5352.0000", "5644.0000", "6354.0000", 
    "651.0000", "6732.0000", "68634.0000", "6874.0000", "709.0000", 
    "7236.0000", "724.0000", "73.0000", "78170.0000", "7844.0000", 
    "811.0000", "8500.0000", "8535.0000", "9505.0000", "9509.0000", 
    "9826.0000", "9827.0000", "1278.0000", "140000.0000", "1475.0000", 
    "1481.0000", "1838.0000", "1871.0000", "2002.0000", "20439.0000", 
    "2143.0000", "23202.0000", "2611.0000", "2775.0000", "3028.0000", 
    "3031.0000", "3032.0000", "320.0000", "3356.0000", "36000.0000", 
    "3656.0000", "3705.0000", "3748.0000", "40438.0000", "41491.0000", 
    "4250.0000", "5375.0000", "5681.0000", "5750.0000", "60000.0000", 
    "639.0000", "67500.0000", "67568.0000", "70000.0000", "7500.0000", 
    "8707.0000", "8709.0000", "92807.0000", "10417.0000", "1061.0000", 
    "1088.0000", "1198.0000", "1199.0000", "123.0000", "1433.0000", 
    "1590.0000", "1604.0000", "1641.0000", "1930.0000", "1931.0000", 
    "2022.0000", "2023.0000", "2055.0000", "2311.0000", "276.0000", 
    "2901.0000", "32412.0000", "3398.0000", "3399.0000", "3400.0000", 
    "3408.0000", "346.0000", "357.0000", "3653.0000", "4159.0000", 
    "4160.0000", "459.0000", "525.0000", "530.0000", "55316.0000", 
    "593.0000", "669.0000", "720.0000", "721.0000", "774.0000", 
    "999.0000", "106447.0000", "11874.0000", "13759.0000", "150.0000", 
    "153060.0000", "15888.0000", "1652.0000", "180.0000", "19477.0000", 
    "2216.0000", "231.0000", "28859.0000", "32309.0000", "35449.0000", 
    "6790.0000", "8960.0000", "9045.0000", "10524.0000", "109027.0000", 
    "11250.0000", "11900.0000", "11976.0000", "14500.0000", "17023.0000", 
    "1828.0000", "200.0000", "22500.0000", "25741.0000", "2626.0000", 
    "26759.0000", "3350.0000", "3550.0000", "36527.0000", "38473.0000", 
    "450.0000", "4874.0000", "50403.0000", "7246.0000", "7400.0000", 
    "7754.0000", "9422.0000", "54000.0000", "10006.0000", "104.0000", 
    "11319.0000", "13697.0000", "15281.0000", "161120.0000", 
    "16317.0000", "2046.0000", "2188.0000", "254396.0000", "28924.0000", 
    "300.0000", "3001.0000", "31380.0000", "3272.0000", "3632.0000", 
    "5581.0000", "7094.0000", "730.0000", "8006.0000", "8187.0000", 
    "1001.0000", "10611.0000", "10744.0000", "12695.0000", "1300.0000", 
    "13462.0000", "1400.0000", "1435.0000", "14964.0000", "16575.0000", 
    "1700.0000", "1713.0000", "1799.0000", "1901.0000", "1948.0000", 
    "2134.0000", "2294.0000", "2400.0000", "25359.0000", "3000.0000", 
    "312.0000", "3150.0000", "31513.0000", "34100.0000", "3510.0000", 
    "3600.0000", "3699.0000", "3710.0000", "3810.0000", "4038.0000", 
    "40969.0000", "4100.0000", "4477.0000", "4523.0000", "4524.0000", 
    "4597.0000", "4799.0000", "5129.0000", "5150.0000", "5324.0000", 
    "5379.0000", "5600.0000", "58355.0000", "5900.0000", "6078.0000", 
    "6388.0000", "6808.0000", "6966.0000", "700.0000", "703.0000", 
    "7272.0000", "7300.0000", "7506.0000", "7920.0000", "794.0000", 
    "8300.0000", "8900.0000", "9118.0000", "37500.0000", "10232.0000", 
    "11200.0000", "1204.0000", "12260.0000", "153000.0000", "17259.0000", 
    "17260.0000", "17931.0000", "1825.0000", "19014.0000", "20465.0000", 
    "21690.0000", "2173.0000", "2370.0000", "2784.0000", "29027.0000", 
    "29520.0000", "2955.0000", "297.0000", "3200.0000", "36782.0000", 
    "3700.0000", "3741.0000", "3871.0000", "4119.0000", "4209.0000", 
    "4534.0000", "48000.0000", "4903.0000", "4969.0000", "51779.0000", 
    "558000.0000", "6545.0000", "6716.0000", "7962.0000", "8000.0000", 
    "8240.0000", "8425.0000", "8775.0000", "8888.0000", "9500.0000", 
    "9810.0000", "1025.0000", "1140.0000", "2030.0000", "2281.0000", 
    "100000.0000", "12105.0000", "13123.0000", "133499.0000", 
    "15266.0000", "183570.0000", "9000.0000", "10089.0000", "10781.0000", 
    "11192.0000", "1162.0000", "11757.0000", "11800.0000", "1363.0000", 
    "15031.0000", "1576.0000", "163281.0000", "19579.0000", "1960.0000", 
    "20104.0000", "2024.0000", "2157.0000", "2330.0000", "2371.0000", 
    "2372.0000", "24299.0000", "25550.0000", "2607.0000", "2608.0000", 
    "2798.0000", "3474.0000", "3898.0000", "40359.0000", "40820.0000", 
    "4312.0000", "4469.0000", "4676.0000", "5026.0000", "61744.0000", 
    "6316.0000", "6391.0000", "785.0000", "8394.0000", "879.0000", 
    "887.0000", "1409.0000", "14350.0000", "17514.0000", "199.0000", 
    "2430.0000", "2529.0000", "2964.0000", "3587.0000", "583.0000", 
    "7153.0000", "7443.0000", "7657.0000", "8640.0000", "1005.0000", 
    "109.0000", "1122.0000", "11860.0000", "12349.0000", "1282.0000", 
    "131.0000", "13521.0000", "1366.0000", "13978.0000", "1430.0000", 
    "14312.0000", "1620.0000", "16359.0000", "1699.0522", "1817.0000", 
    "1954.0000", "2018.0000", "2102.0000", "21780.0000", "2182.0000", 
    "2374.0000", "24065.0000", "247.0000", "2470.0000", "2627.8701", 
    "2810.0000", "30297.0000", "315.0000", "3307.0000", "3462.0000", 
    "3578.0000", "358.0000", "3830.0000", "3916.0000", "4021.0000", 
    "4089.0000", "4391.0000", "4412.0000", "470.0000", "4742.0000", 
    "4776.0000", "4860.0000", "5045.0000", "5110.0000", "5465.0000", 
    "607.0000", "6418.0000", "659.0000", "672.0000", "740.0000", 
    "7417.0000", "750.0000", "7574.0000", "7818.0000", "7881.0000", 
    "8072.0000", "8731.0000", "9047.0000", "1223.0000", "127.0000", 
    "128.0000", "16428.0000", "1842.0000", "22772.0000", "41193.0000", 
    "517.0000", "5389.0000", "5928.0000", "6761.0000", "6881.0000", 
    "76.0000", "77.0000", "10400.0000", "107416.0000", "128299.0000", 
    "17000.0000", "275000.0000", "278407.0000", "31500.0000", 
    "416667.0000", "479271.0000", "493.0000", "577901.0000", 
    "627901.0000", "750000.0000", "80000.0000", "85.0000", "952676.0000", 
    "3727.0000", "554.0000", "12623.0000", "13135.0000", "14579.0000", 
    "16901.0000", "2049.0000", "21755.0000", "22338.0000", "2246.0000", 
    "2373.0000", "24538.0000", "28389.0000", "3265.0000", "3729.0000", 
    "39462.0000", "3954.0000", "50494.0000", "5584.0000", "5585.0000", 
    "6134.0000", "6718.0000", "68604.0000", "6991.0000", "7145.0000", 
    "758.0000", "8197.0000", "9089.0000", "9865.0000", "110.0000", 
    "1120.0000", "1165.0000", "12000.0000", "1586.0000", "2142.0000", 
    "2927.0000", "30000.0000", "952.0000", "3844.0000", "48403.0000", 
    "533.0000", "6878.0000", "101.0000", "10599.0000", "11000.0000", 
    "1125.0000", "1186.0000", "122.0000", "12200.0000", "12320.0000", 
    "1344.0000", "1373.0000", "1380.0000", "1432.0000", "14726.0000", 
    "1524.0000", "1529.0000", "15500.0000", "1555.0000", "1568.0000", 
    "15762.0000", "1780.0000", "1800.0000", "1841.0000", "1875.0000", 
    "1979.0000", "2084.0000", "2152.0000", "233.0000", "2409.0000", 
    "2443.0000", "2635.0000", "2835.0000", "2899.0000", "3070.0000", 
    "3080.0000", "3096.0000", "3136.0000", "3146.0000", "3296.0000", 
    "3405.0000", "3419.0000", "3751.0000", "3757.0000", "3849.0000", 
    "4106.0000", "4107.0000", "4292.0000", "4321.0000", "4645.0000", 
    "4901.0000", "4931.0000", "503.0000", "5060.0000", "5316.0000", 
    "5317.0000", "5412.0000", "5497.0000", "5557.0000", "5838.0000", 
    "5862.0000", "6083.0000", "6168.0000", "6323.0000", "802.0000", 
    "8487.0000", "9635.0000", "13378.0000", "14906.0000", "1537.0000", 
    "1643.0000", "21393.0000", "2191.0000", "23384.0000", "23670.0000", 
    "2451.0000", "25578.0000", "28974.0000", "2982.0000", "3123.0000", 
    "3134.0000", "31343.0000", "3246.0000", "334.0000", "3426.0000", 
    "3513.0000", "360.0000", "399.0000", "41123.0000", "4357.0000", 
    "436.0000", "4404.0000", "443.0000", "523.0000", "545.0000", 
    "5511.0000", "62829.0000", "6309.0000", "6783.0000", "7170.0000", 
    "787.0000", "793.0000", "87503.0000", "103.0000", "10854.0000", 
    "110000.0000", "11108.0000", "1273.0000", "1419.0000", "1503.0000", 
    "15790.0000", "1615.0000", "164.0000", "18440.0000", "1911.0000", 
    "1932.0000", "1942.0000", "2369.0000", "2497.0000", "26400.0000", 
    "2919.0000", "292000.0000", "2995.0000", "2996.0000", "31422.0000", 
    "3371.0000", "3503.0000", "3504.0000", "3643.0000", "3892.0000", 
    "3948.0000", "3987.0000", "4146.0000", "496.0000", "5203.0000", 
    "58.0000", "6685.0000", "68.0000", "727.0000", "9220.0000", 
    "34000.0000", "1325.0000", "140.0000", "2040.0000", "260.0000", 
    "261.0000", "268.0000", "285.0000", "306.0000", "407.0000", 
    "408.0000", "425.0000", "434.0000", "442.0000", "4759.0000", 
    "501.0000", "51.0000", "519.0000", "52.0000", "54.0000", 
    "55.0000", "763.0000", "764.0000", "828.0000", "95.0000", 
    "96.0000", "988.0000", "1011.0000", "102915.0000", "103367.0000", 
    "10460.0000", "10603.0000", "108193.0000", "1172.0000", "1175.0000", 
    "11823.0000", "14072.0000", "141881.0000", "143120.0000", 
    "14724.0000", "147607.0000", "154400.0000", "15745.0000", 
    "15831.0000", "16526.0000", "18100.0000", "19589.0000", "20700.0000", 
    "2100.0000", "211406.0000", "215868.0000", "24100.0000", 
    "25413.0000", "257965.0000", "34.0000", "35340.0000", "36700.0000", 
    "37845.0000", "39448.0000", "398.0000", "40205.0000", "4025.0000", 
    "449.0000", "4653.0000", "467.0000", "487.0000", "494.0000", 
    "4964.0000", "512076.0000", "58767.0000", "636.0000", "681.0000", 
    "691.0000", "70680.0000", "725.0000", "7843.0000", "834.0000", 
    "844.0000", "86.0000", "874.0000", "976.0000", "9927.0000", 
    "8965.0000", "10025.0000", "10150.0000", "103454.0000", "11516.0000", 
    "120324.0000", "12641.0000", "13000.0000", "13700.0000", 
    "14000.0000", "14611.0000", "19750.0000", "2225.0000", "24351.0000", 
    "24653.0000", "25.0000", "25000.0000", "252225.0000", "26888.0000", 
    "286671.0000", "29500.0000", "30007.0000", "305.0000", "30775.0000", 
    "30992.0000", "324.0000", "36500.0000", "36965.0000", "37951.0000", 
    "38099.0000", "38300.0000", "43500.0000", "43720.0000", "44771.0000", 
    "48312.0000", "5004.0000", "50293.0000", "5217240.0000", 
    "5308.0000", "5349.0000", "53767.0000", "58000.0000", "58862.0000", 
    "59863.0000", "6047.0000", "60876.0000", "6215.0000", "63061.0000", 
    "73423.0000", "75347.0000", "79035.0000", "91677.0000", "92779.0000", 
    "1041.0000", "1211.0000", "41401.0000", "4282.0000", "772.0000", 
    "0.0000", "108920.0000", "1374.0000", "1487639.0000", "1567.0000", 
    "1918587.0000", "1951219.0000", "19569979.0000", "200637.0000", 
    "2456822.0000", "26611.0000", "300000.0000", "335279.0000", 
    "3455129.0000", "3907165.0000", "4280.0000", "431489.0000", 
    "4403409.0000", "49303.0000", "5000000.0000", "76190.0000", 
    "8433.0000", "85191.0000", "9626.0000", "981282.0000", "1038.0000", 
    "12131.0000", "133334.0000", "1669.0000", "1921.0000", "1980.0000", 
    "2331.0000", "2600.0000", "2630.0000", "2959.0000", "378232.0000", 
    "40235.0000", "4138.0000", "4407.0000", "4473.0000", "4959.0000", 
    "49921.0000", "51688.0000", "5302.0000", "5726.0000", "7105.0000", 
    "8635.0000", "96534.0000", "1096.0000", "12386.0000", "12614.0000", 
    "13726.0000", "14640.0000", "14951.0000", "151.0000", "155.0000", 
    "159.0000", "162.0000", "166.0000", "181.0000", "182.0000", 
    "184.0000", "186.0000", "188.0000", "18902.0000", "19376.0000", 
    "205.0000", "207.0000", "20706.0000", "209.0000", "211.0000", 
    "213.0000", "220.0000", "235.0000", "2604.0000", "28186.0000", 
    "286.0000", "314.0000", "31436.0000", "34976.0000", "350.0000", 
    "3730.0000", "3731.0000", "3745.0000", "385.0000", "4019.0000", 
    "42282.0000", "432.0000", "448.0000", "5091.0000", "5373.0000", 
    "5650.0000", "581.0000", "6115.0000", "658.0000", "6981.0000", 
    "7462.0000", "7523.0000", "7761.0000", "8106.0000", "829.0000", 
    "84.0000", "875.0000", "8964.0000", "898.0000", "935.0000", 
    "9762.0000"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you share some sample data using `dput` along with what you want the final result to look like (images aren't very helpful).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am not that familiar with dput, when I make that call on the data frame I mentioned its a huge amount of text that won't fit in this chat.  Ideally, after the filtering criteria, if there are any matches, I would be left with that list of identifiers. If you can tell how to best display the data for you, I will put it in the chat.

Comment: assuming your `data.frame` is called InsiderList3, you can use `dput(InsiderList3[1:50, ])` to share the first 50 rows.

Comment: Strangely, even I select 10 rows the output is 50k characters.  I'm trying to past it into the question.

Comment: In that case you should limit it to fewer columns to create a minium working example

Comment: Thanks so much for helping.  I have updated the initial question to reflect the trimmed data frame's dput.  Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So you want for each `Insider.CIK` what the first transaction was, and to have all Sale following Purchase or vice versa in the 90 day window for that same CIK ?

Comment: I want to filter the table based on the first value for the corresponding index ID to check if an offsetting transaction for that ID is available within 90 days.  i.e. for a purchase and sale with 90 days prior and vice versa.  If there are any ID's that satisfy this condition then I'd like to be able to see then otherwise, if not, a null value. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a nicer solution, but I would do it as follows

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- as.data.table(InsiderList3)

setnames(DT, gsub(" ", ".", colnames(DT)))

setkey(DT, Insider.CIK, Transaction.Date)

# Mark the 90 day period
DT[, minDate := min(Transaction.Date), by=Insider.CIK]
DT[Transaction.Date - days(90) <= MinDate, DateMatch := 1]

# Mark all firms whose first transactions are S or P
DT[Transaction.Date==min(Transaction.Date) & Transaction.Type %in% c("S-Sale", "P-Purchase"), FirstTransaction := Transaction.Type, by=Insider.CIK]
DT[, FirstTransaction := unique(FirstTransaction), by=Insider.CIK]

# Then you can filter based on the two criteria
DT.SP <- DT[DateMatch==1 & FirstTransaction=="S-Sale" & Transaction.Type=="P-Purchase"]
DT.PS <- DT[DateMatch==1 & FirstTransaction=="P-Sale" & Transaction.Type=="S-Purchase"]
```

This is a quick and dirty filtering... I'm sure there's a way to do this in fewer lines of code, but this should work. Pretty or not, the solution should be pretty fast since it uses `data.table`.